# Template method for a non-template class

Tags: java

I have a class with one private method, which now returns `Object` type, so that other public methods calling this private method do typecasting - either to `JSONObject`  or `JSONArray`. This is how it looks like:

```
private Object __loader(String file_name){
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
   Object obj = null;
   try{
       obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file_name));
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return obj;
}

public JSONArray method1(){
    return (JSONArray) this.__loader("file1.json");
}

public JSONObject method1(){
    return (JSONObject) this.__loader("file2.json");
}
```

So, as you can see, in one case I do typecasting from `Object` to `JSONArray` and in other case from `Object` to `JSONObject`. I do not really like that, since that does not seem to be pure Java and OOP. So, what is the best way to implement this? (PS. I guess I may have a factory class for this, but probably there is a lighter solution).

Comment: You've just got to cast. How can you know from a filename what type of json object you will get back when you parse its contents?

Comment: I would say, using `Object` in the return type is not pure Java and OOP. If you definitely have to remove the casting, then you have to write two different private method which returns the appropriate return type (Now it'll be pure Java but not as an 100% OOP since you've duplicated the code). I consider the current code as good and you don't have any way to remove the casting.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, I think, factory class in the only way to do it in OOP style.

Comment: @Andy Turner. In fact there is no guarantee that files will contain only pure json. But I think, if there is some garbage, then __loader will throw an error.

Comment: Right. The compiler simply can't know in advance, hence the parser returning Object (or throwing an exception), so you need to cast the result yourself.